# Google Maps Javascript API stuck in lite mode

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, api-key, google-maps-lite

Since one week, my project website is stuck with the lite mode by default.
The problem is when we zoom fast in the map, we see some spike lag.

Mostly in chrome and mobile. In firefox i dont see much spike lag.

To see differences between lite mode and full mode : 
full mode : https://www.google.ca/maps/@45.503366,-73.5853116,13z?hl=en
lite mode : https://www.google.com/maps/@45.4754748,-73.5526631,12z?force=lite

I'm not the only one who get stuck with that problem. Here example
padmapper dat com
kangalou dat com
There is one week, if my memory is good was all in full mode, now in lite mode.

Me and kangalou website have this new warning i didnt have last week.
Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys

i had this one but whatever..
Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired

I created my API key etc but i'm not sure where tu put that parameter.
I'm not sure that without the API key now we get stuck in lite mode, i take a guess, maybe it's not that.

Comment: my material acceleration in chrome advanced is active.
im on linux but i tested on Windows and others PC.
WIth last version of chrome 49.0.2623.87 64 bits

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps JavaScript API doesn't have a 'lite' mode like the desktop website @ google.com/maps does. The Google Maps JavaScript API doesn't support the full 3D-experience that google.com/maps can provide and usually looks and acts much closer to the 'lite' mode you've seen using so it's easy to confuse the two.

The warnings you are experiencing, like not using an API key or using the unneeded `sensor` parameter sound like you should work through the [getting started guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) to make sure you're following the latest best practices.